# how to create a FEM mesh with "RegionPlot" where the sample points are a function of the position

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I need to resolve the diffusion equation in a domain with circular sources (holes).

I've tried defining the whole region with holes but the result is very mesh-dependent and not symmetric, so at the moment I'm imposing the symmetry myself by only solving 1/4th of the system.

```
cords = Table[{i, 0}, {i, {0, 5}}];
Ω = Apply[And, Norm[{x, y} - #]^2 > 1 & /@ cords]

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[ 
   ImplicitRegion[
    And[x > 0 && 
      y > 0 && ( x - 2)^2 + y^2 <= 900, Ω], {x, y}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .5, "ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False,
    "MaxCellMeasure" -> 10, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", 
     "SamplePoints" -> 300}];
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Having so many sample points makes the mesh creation really slow, so I would like to have a way to make the resolution position-dependent, having more resolution on the region plot near the centre and less in the outer border.

EDIT:

The problem I have is that I need to go to relatively large regions, and if I use the mesh refining option as user21 recommends, I end up with something like this:

[image: zoom in for the region user21 proposes but with a 2 outer radius]

A coarse approximation to the solution is two logarithmic decays from the centre of each particle, so I'd like the resolution of the boundary to go like that.

EDIT2:

somebody should have told me, "don't try FEM in V10.0", most of the other problems I was having disappeared after updating.

Not only the MeshRefinementFunction works as expected in 10.3 but also the solution is much more symmetric and continuous for the cases I'm looking at. I don't think it's only because the mesh is better made in the new version, seems like a more robust solver, at least from the user side of it.

Despite "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" not accepting a function of position, the MeshRefinementFunction can be used to refine wherever one wants to. In my case I'm looking at something like this:

```
MeshRefinementFunction -> 
 Function[{vertices, area}, 
  area > 0.0125 (0.1 + 
      If[Norm[Mean[vertices] - {2.5, 0}] < 5, 4, 
       4 + Norm[Mean[vertices] - {2.5, 0}]^2])
```

Which is pretty much exactly what I wanted to achieve when i posed the question. Thanks user21!

**Update**

The problem seems to persist in mma 11, at least in my mac.

[image]

Even thought the refinement function is quite fine:

[image]

Comment: You might try constructing your own boundary mesh. Code will look like `ToElementMesh[
 ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> ..., "BoundaryElements" -> { ...}]]`

Comment: There are a few missing pieces of information - what is `Ω3`, and what is `Ω` needed for? Why does the boundary mesh generator need to be region plot?

Comment: Sorry, omega is the region where do the meshing, omega 3 was a typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, \[Pi]/2}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1/25]], Disk[{3/10, 0}, 1/25]], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.0005 (0.1 + 2 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For a larger domain:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 5, {0, \[Pi]/2}], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1/25]], Disk[{3/10, 0}, 1/25]], 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.0005 (0.1 + Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];
mesh["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1}, {-0.1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with MeshRefinement is that it does precisely what it say, it refines an already existing mesh. The problem is that as I make the outer circle larger, the resolution of the smaller half circles diminish, so refining the mesh resulted in a very refined square in the worst case I tried, let me see if I can recover the problem. I guess what I'm looking for is something like a "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" that accepts a function of the position instead of a single value.

Comment: for example, if I run your code with a outer radius of 2 the central half disk becomes a triangle, very resolved.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, What do you mean with "the central half disk becomes a triangle"? The `MeshRefinementFunction` does the refinement during the mesh creation, there is no initial mesh that is refined. There is no way to have "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" accept a function of position.

Comment: I hope the image explains what I mean by the disk becoming a triangle.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, that's because you use the region plot boundary mesh generator. Use the default one, that works better. Possibly you'd need to get a newer version of Mathematica?

Comment: I guess it's the version since I just copy pasted your code. I still have V10.0, gonna get the new one and try it again.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, yes, since the default boundary mesh generator changed with 10.2 (I think) so the current one (10.3.1) should do fine.

Comment: have you tried this code on the new versions of mathematica? 10.4.1 and 11 give me the same error

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, when I run the code from this answer in 11 - I get the expected result an no error.

Comment: maybe it's a mac problem? I'm running V11 in Mac OSX 10.11.5 Added a picture of the results I get.

Comment: I need to ask a coworker to look at that since I do not have a mac. Here is something you could try before: What happens if you set the `"SymbolicProcessing"` of the `SystemOptions["FiniteElementOptions"]` to a value larger then 1. ?

Comment: tried with 2. 10. amd 100., nothing happens.

Comment: Here is another idea: you could use ``Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 5, {0, \[Pi]/2}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1/25]], Disk[{3/10, 0}, 1/25]], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.00025 (0.1 + 2 Mean[vertices][[2]])]][
 "Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1}, {-0.1, 1}}]]``. If the whole x-axes is too much you could dampen that out with a function after the cutaway disks.

Comment: still doesn't work if you go to a radius of 15 for the larger half disk, I think this is really either a bug or somehow my computers are broken.

Comment: No, I think you just need to adjust the mesh refinement function.

Comment: the mesh is quite fine, but it seems like the feature of the region are not resolved in that mesh but in a previous step, which is dependent on the system size.