# Problem when using the MeshRefinementFunction option of FEM`ToElementMesh

Tags: regions, mesh, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve Stokes equation in the following domain

[image]

The border of the inner half circle where I define a certain boundary condition different from zero and where I am interested in obtaining a smooth solution for the pressure. To obtain a smooth result I need to use a fairly small grid on the centre of the domain an my plan was to use position-dependent grid to speed up the computation.

While checking different functions to use for the `MeshRefinementFunction` I found the following:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Table[
  z0 = 0;
  r2 = 
    RegionIntersection[ 
      RegionDifference[
        Cuboid[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], 
        RegionUnion[Disk[{0, -z0}, 1], Disk[{0, z0}, 1]]], 
      Disk[{0, 0}, L]];
    mesh = 
      ToElementMesh[r2, 
        MeshRefinementFunction -> 
          Function[{vertices, area}, 
            area > 0.00125 (1 + Norm[Abs[Mean[vertices]] - {0, 0}])^2]];
  Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}}], 
  {L, 10., 20, 5}]
```

[image]

See how the resolution of the inner circle is lost. Something similar happened [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103389/how-to-create-a-fem-mesh-with-regionplot-where-the-sample-points-are-a-functio)

However, if I define the `MaxCellMeasure` the problem disappears

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[ r2, "MaxCellMeasure" -> .005]
```

[image]

The problem seems to be the ratio between system size and grid resolution since the same happens in the first case if I decrease the refinement constant for a given system size.

Using `MaxBoundaryCellMeasure` is not a solution btw, since it introduces other problems of its own. Using such a small grid uniformly makes the computation very time consuming and I don't really need such resolution on the outer half circle.

So, is this is a bug? Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

Try using `AccuracyGoal`

```
Table[

 z0 = 0;
 r2 = RegionIntersection[
   RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-L, -L}, {L, L}],
    RegionUnion[Disk[{0, -z0}, 1], Disk[{0, z0}, 1]]],
   Disk[{0, 0}, L]];

mesh = ToElementMesh[r2,
   MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vertices, area},
     area > 0.00125 (1 + Norm[Abs[Mean[vertices]] - {0, 0}])^2],
   AccuracyGoal -> 2];
```

[image]

---

The issue seems to be related to the automatic improvement of boundary position.

```
Table[

 z0 = 0;
 r2 = RegionIntersection[
   RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-L, -L}, {L, L}],
    RegionUnion[Disk[{0, -z0}, 1], Disk[{0, z0}, 1]]],
   Disk[{0, 0}, L]];

 mesh = ToElementMesh[r2,
   MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vertices, area},
     area > 0.00125 (1 + Norm[Abs[Mean[vertices]] - {0, 0}])^2],
   "ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False];

 (*mesh["Wireframe"]*)

 Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}}], {L, 10., 20,
   5}]
```

[image]

As a solution, I've often used [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) (which also eliminates those annoying extrapolation warnings)

```
Table[

 z0 = 0;
 r2 = RegionIntersection[
   RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-L, -L}, {L, L}],
    RegionUnion[Disk[{0, -z0}, 1], Disk[{0, z0}, 1]]],
   Disk[{0, 0}, L]];

 mesh = DiscretizeRegion[r2,
   MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vertices, area},
     area > 0.00125 (1 + Norm[Abs[Mean[vertices]] - {0, 0}])^2],
   Method -> "Continuation", AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];

 (*mesh["Wireframe"]*)

 Show[mesh, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}}], {L, 10., 20, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: your first method, if I add a small value for `"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure"` seems to solve the problem quite nicely. As for the annoying warnings, I'm using `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {# &, "WarningMessage" -> False}` and seems to work quite well. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: when setting AccuracyGoal the mesh is created nicely but the result is completely unphysical. It also throws a warning about comparing real and imaginary numbers. Any clues why? I can update the code to show that if you are interested.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa sure, I'm interested

Comment: took me a while to find a minimal working example and while doing so discovered that the error with `AccuracyGoal` appears only when I define the interpolation function as I did in my previous comment. If I delete that, the `accuracyGoal` solution is better than the one with MaxBoundaryCellMeasure. Both have ugly discontinuities when looking at the inner circle though, so some method of extrapolation is necessary.  Tomorrow I will check your discretizeRegion method.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa using `DiscretizeRegion` is not the same as using `ToElementMesh` careful here. The difference is that `DiscretizeRegion` will only produce a first order accurate mesh while `ToElementMesh` will by default generate a second order mesh which in turn will result in a better FEM solution. See the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @user21 I realised after running some test that the solution when using `DiscretizeRegion` was worse. At the end I'm back at the beginning using just a small mesh but is like the errors on my second figure are inherited by the solution and have fluctuations on that wavelength. Very weird situation,  I'm trying to set a minimal example that reproduces the problem but is difficult to make a small working example without making a gigantic code dump. Will try though.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, yes, if you could try to reduce it as much as possible that would certainly be good. I suspect that boundary conditions may not be applied as expected. But that really is a shot in the dark.